# Determining Cause of Suspended Website on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Website hosted on Windows Azure. This website is a custom ASP.NET MVC 4 site hosted as a shared web site instance. Within the past couple of days, I've started to get large spikes in CPU Time. These spikes have been sustained and have caused my web site to get suspended. However, I'm not sure how to determine the cause of these spikes. Here is what I've done so far:

1. I attempted to look at the diagnostics via the Windows Azure FTP drop. I did not see anything there.
2. I reviewed my Google Analytics to see if there was anything out of the ordinary. The site had 20 visitors yesterday. So nothing crazy.

How can I identify the culprit of the the CPU spike? Once it spikes, it just sits there for hours. I'm not sure what would cause this.

Thank you

Comment: Could you also deploy your project to another host (e.g. Azure Web Role) where you can use a profiler or some other third party monitoring solution? Are you sure that there is nothing like a web search indexing or something similar going on causing a burst of requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running your site on your local box and simulating your visitor traffic, exercising all your website's features?

Testing locally is 1000's of times easier and more revealing than trying to debug a site that's running live.

If you still can't find anything wrong when running locally, consider using [logging and tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx) to strategic points in your site so that you can see how often, and how long it takes for your site to execute complex operations.